# How I can push my state elements to the state array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to push my state elements (`user_number_X`) into an array (`this.state.results.numbers`) but my input handler function is not working.

How can I rewrite it so it will push input values into an array?

Here is my code:

```
export default class InputArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      draw_number: '',
      user_number_1: '',
      user_number_2: '',
      user_number_3: '',
      user_number_4: '',
      user_number_5: '',
      user_number_6: '',
      results : {
        numbers: [],
        draws: ''
      }
    }
  }

  /* handledrawsChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      event
    })
  } */

  inputHandler = event => { 
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    this.state.results.numbers.push(event.target.value)
    // this.state.results.numbers.push(event.target.value)//this.setState({number: this.state.results.numbers.push(parseInt(event.target.value))});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/simulate", {
      method: "POST",
      body: this.state.results
    });
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
      return (
        <InputField>
          <InputWrapper>
            <Label>1st number</Label>
            <Input name="user_number_1" type="number" maxlength="2" value={this.state.user_number_1} onChange={this.inputHandler} required></Input>
            <Label>2nd number</Label>
            <Input name="user_number_2" type="number" maxlength="2" value={this.state.user_number_2} onChange={this.inputHandler} required></Input>
            <Label>3rd number</Label>
            <Input name="user_number_3" type="number" maxlength="2" value={this.state.user_number_3} onChange={this.inputHandler} required></Input>
            <Label>4th number</Label>
            <Input name="user_number_4" type="number" maxlength="2" value={this.state.user_number_4} onChange={this.inputHandler} required></Input>
            <Label>5th number</Label>
            <Input name="user_number_5" type="number" maxlength="2" value={this.state.user_number_5} onChange={this.inputHandler} required></Input>
            <Label>6th number</Label>
            <Input name="user_number_6" type="number" maxlength="2" value={this.state.user_number_6} onChange={this.inputHandler} required></Input>
            <Label>Number of draws:</Label>
            <Input name="draw_number" type="number" value={this.state.draw_number} onChange={this.inputHandler} required></Input>
          </InputWrapper>
          <Button type="submit" /*onClick={this.drawsHandler}*/>Let's win!</Button>
        </InputField>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to put a new value in `this.state.results.numbers` array every time an input changes?

Comment: This code is wrong on so many levels. You are trying to mutate state by changing it manually. The implementation of the controlled component is broken. You are changing the event of a controlled component to change another variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `concat()` and use Object Destructuring for cleaner code

```
const {results} = this.state; 
const {numbers} = results
this.setState({results:{...results,numbers:numbers.concat([event.target.value])}}
```

Comment: should I do this in the global scope or in `inputHandler` method?

Comment: Obviously in `inputHandler` and keep the other line `this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})` as it is

Comment: it works, but it pushes a lot of unnecessary numbers into the array, for example, if I input 23, it will add `["2", "23"]` to the array

Comment: @Leocete Which event you are using on the the `<input>` Use `onChange` in will fix the problem.

Comment: I'm using onChange